# Sort a collection and rank the result based on certain criteria

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

Say I have the following

```
var searches = new ObservableCollection<Book>();
```

`searches` contains the book objects

```
public class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set;}
    public string Desc {get; set;}    
}
```

I want to sort `searches` by a matching string. First it checks the `Title` than rank them based on how close the search string from the beginning of `Title`. Next it checks `Desc` and rank them by how close the search string appears from the beginning of the `Desc.

For example if I have

> Book 1
>   Title: ABC Book Title
>   Desc: The description of book 1
>
> Book 2
>   Title: Book Title Only
>   Desc: There's an ABC in the description of book 2
>
> Book 3
>   Title: Book Title ABC
>   Desc: ABC is in the beginning

So let say the search keyword is `ABC`, I want `searches` to be sorted so that I get the  following. The result place higher priority to items that contains the search string in the title.

> Book 1
>   Title: ABC Book Title
>   Desc: The description of book 1
>
> Book 3
>   Title: Book Title ABC
>   Desc: ABC is in the beginning
>
> Book 2
>   Title: Book Title Only
>   Desc: There's an ABC in the description of book 2

How do I achieve this using LINQ?

Comment: What  have you tried so far. Having a go is the best way to learn although I do struggle with the more complicated side of LINQ myself

Comment: Have you tried using a custom `IComparer` and `Sort`/`OrderBy`?

Comment: @CodeBlend I could only compare title and rank it by ascending or descending order. I struggled with the second comparison and how to use LINQ to detect how close the string from the beginning

Comment: @chrfin I wish I were familiar with IComparer. I just do not know how to include the second requirement `Desc` in LINQ and checking how close the search string from the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to suggestion by @M Patel and Stefano, I've arrived at the following solution

```
var sorted = searches.Select(tile => new { TileViewModel = tile, Rank = rankResult(tile, text) })
                    .OrderByDescending(r => r.Rank)
                    .Select(r => r.TileViewModel);

SearchResultsTilesVM = new ObservableCollection<TileViewModel>(sorted);
```

The method that take the position of the keyword. I added extra point if a match is found in the title.

```
    private int rankResult(TileViewModel vm, string keyword)
    {
        double rank = 0;

        //Added 100 to give stronger weight when keyword found in title
        int index = vm.Title.IndexOf(keyword, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

        if (index >= 0 )
        {
            rank = (double)(vm.Title.Length - index) / (double)vm.Title.Length * 100 + 100;
        }         

        int index2 = vm.Information.IndexOf(keyword, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

        if (index2 >= 0)
        {
            rank += (double)(vm.Information.Length - index2) / (double)vm.Information.Length * 100;
        }

        return Convert.ToInt32(rank);
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use a rank function to define a "score" for each book and then sort by score.

i.e.

```
var searchString = "ABC";
var results = books.Select(b => new { Book = b, Rank = RankBook(b, searchString) })
                   .OrderBy(r => r.Rank)
                   .Select(r => r.Book.Title);
```

And the rank function:

```
private int RankBook(Book b, string searchString)
{
    int rank = 0;
    if (b.Title.Contains(searchString)) rank += 10;

    if (b.Desc.Contains(searchString)) rank += 5;

    return rank;
}
```

This is saying: found in title=10 point, found in desc=5 points, so uo get the most relevant books with higher scores.

Comment: Good idea. However I also want to consider how close the search string from the beginning of the title and its description..

Comment: You can easily improve the rank function to adjust the score depending on the index of the string.

Answer (score 5):

You can use OrderBy and ThenBy

```
var searches = new ObservableCollection<Book>();

searches.Add(new Book()
{
    Desc = "The description of book 1",
    Title = "ABC Book Title"
});

searches.Add(new Book()
{
    Desc = "Book Title Only",
    Title = "There's an ABC in the description of book 2"
});

searches.Add(new Book()
{
    Desc = "Book Title ABC",
    Title = "ABC is in the beginning"
});

var ordered = new ObservableCollection<Book>(searches.OrderBy(book => book.Title).ThenBy(book => book.Desc.Contains("ABC")));
```

### Update

I have added a ranking system which will hopefully assist you with what you are looking for. All I use is IndexOf to determine the location of your criteria and store it in a property within the Book object. The other suggestion I have is that you create a standalone collection (using inheritance) for your books, this way you could customise it to your needs without having to write too much code outside the context of the object itself

```
public class BookCollection : ObservableCollection<Book> // Notice the Inheritance to ObservableCollection
{
    public void SetCriteria(string search)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
            return;

        foreach (var book in this)
        {
            if(book.Title.Contains(search))
                book.TitleRank = book.Title.IndexOf(search, StringComparison.InvariantCulture);

            if(book.Desc.Contains(search))
                book.DescRank = book.Desc.IndexOf(search, StringComparison.InvariantCulture);
        }

        var collection = new List<Book>(base.Items.OrderBy(book => book.Title)
                                                  .ThenBy(book => book.Desc)
                                                  .ThenBy(book => book.TitleRank)
                                                  .ThenBy(book => book.DescRank));
        Items.Clear();

        collection.ForEach(Add);
        collection.Clear();
    }
}

public class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    public int TitleRank { get; internal set; }
    public int DescRank { get; internal set; }
}
```

Now to use this new collection, all you have to do is call it like this.

```
var collection = new BookCollection();
collection.Add(new Book { Desc = "Book Title ABC", Title = "ABC is in the beginning" });
// Add your other books here........
collection.SetCriteria("ABC");
// your new collection is now sorted and ready to use, no need to write any extra sorting code here
```

Remember that if you need to add more conditions to your sorting, the only place you have to do this is in the SetCriteria method. Hope this helps.

Comment: Very helpful. However in my case though I would prefer not to create a standalone collection since the requirement is not as complicated. I've combined both answers to arrive at a solution.