# Search like google for a simple database using EF

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, search, full-text-search

Hi I'm creating a simple library system for charity. Now I have a form that allows the users to search for books. To do this work I get a text write in a imput text and use inside a `book => book.Name.Contains(text)` expression (LINQ+EF).

But I want to go a little further. I'm thinking in mix it up a little big and use the same text to find book title, subtitle, author, publishing house, and serie.

Now I have 3 problems:

- Search all columns
- Disregarding the order of the input text words
- Sort the results for the book that most fit into the input text.

I know these topics are a little vague.  But I don't know how or where to started. Someone can get me some help?

Answer (score 0):

Just search over all the fields at the same time.

```
book => book.Name.Contains(text) || book.title.Contains(text) || book.subtitle.Contains(text)
```

etc...

For ranking, it another problem. Doing it in memory will be a lot easier, there are [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23538512/sort-a-collection-and-rank-the-result-based-on-certain-criteria) on SO which can help you.