# top 10 leaderboard tie ranking with grouping

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a database like this which i would like to get the top 10 country ranking with ties with linq to entities. We can use index to solve the ranking problem if tie ranking is omitted. However, what i needed here is to query tie ranking (with tie) of the top 10 country that has most count.

```
ID CountryID
1  1
2  1
3  1
4  2
5  3
........  


db.TableA.GroupBy(p => p.CountryID).
        Select(group =>
           new
           {
             Rank = ????????????
             Count = group.Count(),
             Items = group.Select(i => new
             {
                CountryName = i.Country.CountryName
             }).Distinct()
       }).OrderByDescending(group => group.Count)
```

```html
Rank    CountryName
1       USA
2       UK
2       UK
4       Singapore
5       China
6       France
6       Ukraine
8       Country x
9       Country y
10      Country z
```

Comment: Can you show what results you would expect from the dataset?

Comment: i have edit the post with result expected

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932300/c-sharp-ranking-of-objects-multiple-criteria

Comment: hmm the link seems not really fit with this question. the condition i need here is query with grouping while the link is about ranking without need of grouping. I would be glad if someone could provide answer as pure linq to entity to the solution without involving C# class and logic. I have successfully reproduce the top 10 in order and what i lack of here is to display the ranking with ties